# set multiple floats in one variable?

Tags: c#, floating-point

hey I saw someone do this

// bullet is speed 5, aimed at timmy:

```
float3 v = ((timmy.transform.position - transform.position).Normalized)*5;
bullet.velocity = v;
```

the transform.position are Vector3(float x, float y, float z);

so i thought i could do this

```
private float3 _position;
public Food ()
{
    float3 position = _position(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
}
```

but that says: The type or namespace name `float3' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

so how would i let one variable take multiple values of the same type?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4079451/335858

Comment: There's no `float3` in C# BCL unless you are using a library. But you can implement yours: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17425/A-Vector-Type-for-C

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8145279/335858

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple possibilities.

You can declare a class (or a struct):

```
public class float3
{
    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }
    public float Z { get; set; }
}
```

You can use an array:

```
private float[] _position;
public Food ()
{
    _position = new[] {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
}
```

Or you can use a tuple

```
private Tuple<float,float,float> _position;
public Food ()
{
    _position = Tuple.Create(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
}
```

Comment: I think I like the struct-option best as it retains the X, Y and Z-names.

Comment: I like it better too, but it really dépends on what you want to achieve: creating a new class just for a one-time use is probably overkill. Then I would go with the array if mutability and no enforcing of the length are not a problem. Otherwise, I would prefer the tuple.

Comment: ok thanks, I thought maybe that the 3 stood for how many floats you want to have in one variable, and you could do any number, thats clearly not the case. if these three are my only options i think i'll go for the tuple, never heard of that so always nice to try new things.

Comment: A tuple is like a row in a database, it can have a variety of types (they don't all have to be of the same type) and it has a fixed length like an array.

Comment: is it native C#? I'm using Unity and get this error using tuple: The type or namespace name `Tuple`3' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Tuple has been introduced in .Net 4.0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387150.aspx . I don't know if you can use it in Unity, though.